# Map object to React Child elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-redux

I have a object as follows

I am trying to map it to and create child components based on id and type values. I use this way

```
{[id: 1, type: "string"],
 [id: 2, type: "boolean"]
}.map(data => (
   <Input 
     id= {data.id}
     value={data.type}
   />
))}
```

How do i ensure i can use id and type and pass it to Input component. I saw a working example of array as follows.

```
{['dog', 'cat', 'elephant].map(type => (
  <Input id={type} />
))}
```

Can someone please suggest if i can pass 2 elements to child this way

Comment: The object is malformed. Should it be an array instead? As you're trying to map an object (objects do not have that method).

Comment: How can i use array in my case where i need id and type to be passed too @evolutionxbox

Comment: Do you know what the syntax for an array or an object is? When you know that, this issue should be easily fixable. (I'm too lazy to write an answer...)

Comment: just pack them into objects `{[{id: 1, type: "string"}], [{id: 2, type: "boolean"}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Object.map only for array if you want input object then you need to use

```
object.keys(object).map((_array,index)=>{

   Object(_array).map((_e,_i)=>{
     console.log(_e,"<<<<Elements of array    index>>>",_i)
   })

})
```

just because this is nested array.